# Compare the cells of two columns in two different workbooks and copy values according to the result

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare the cells of the two columns (B) of two different Excel workbooks (W1 and W2) and copy the equal cells of column (D) of workbook W2 into column E of workbook W1.
I make a macro that runs from workbook W1 but I have an error that I can't solve:

I would like to do this in all the sheets of the worksheet W2 but for the moment I'm trying to do this on one sheet.

```
Sub find_and_copy ()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Classeur1").Sheets(1)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .compareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each r In ws1.Range("B2",ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlup))
            If Not IsEmpty(r) Then .add r.Value, r.Row
        Next
        For Each r In ws2.Range("B2", ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If .exists(r.Value) then
                r.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Range("E" & .item(r,Value))
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set ws1 = Nothing: Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

I got the following error message:

> this key is already associated with an item in this collection

Can you help me ?

Comment: You need to test if the key exists before adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(r) Then` should bee `If Not IsEmpty(r) and not .exists(r.Value) Then`